# How to organise files systems according to their extension

Tags: python-3.x, filesystems

I'm new to python programming, i'm learning to write a program to organise files according to their extensions, for instance a user will be prompted to input a path, then a program will iterate through a given path and organise  files extension in a given path.

In the line  `ext = ext[1:] #store extension type`, when the file name is too long i cannot detect a file extension.

I've tried to change an index value to see if i can get different results. For instance with `live_video.mp4`, i want the code to extract `.mp4` from the filename.

```py
try:
    print("Enter directory  or the folder path")
    path = input("Format: C:\\")
    os.path.join(path)
    lst = os.listdir(path)

    for f in lst:  # Iterate through each and every file
        ext = os.path.split(f)
        ext = ext[1:]  # store extension type

        if ext == '':  # Continue to next iteration if its a directory
            continue
        if os.path.exists(path + '/' + ext):  # Move the file to the directory where the name 'ext' already existsenter code here
           shutil.move(path + '/' + f, path + '/' + ext + '/' + f)
```

Answer (score 0):

Install `pytest-shutil` python library first by running
`pip install pytest-shutil` if not already installed.

```
import os
import shutil

try:
    print("Enter directory  or the folder path")
    path = input("Format: C:\\")
    list_ = os.listdir(path)

    for file_ in list_:
        name, ext = os.path.splitext(file_)

        ext = ext[1:]
        if ext == '':
            continue

        if os.path.exists(path + '/' + ext):
            shutil.move(path + '/' + file_, path + '/' + ext + '/' + file_)

        else:
            os.makedirs(path + '/' + ext)
            shutil.move(path + '/' + file_, path + '/' + ext + '/' + file_)
except:
    print('error to throw')
```